# Selecting a record where value falls between two strings in LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

How do you select one or more rows from a table where a specific value falls between the values of two columns?

For example in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE '123ABC' BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue
```

I've tried the following in LINQ (using LINQpad):

```
from d in MyTable
          where d.MinValue.CompareTo("ABBBBC") >= 0 &&
                d.MaxValue.CompareTo("ABBBBC") <= 0
 select d
```

But it just gives me 0 results. If I know the two values in MinValue and MaxValue and insert them instead, for example:

```
from d in MyTable
          where d.MinValue.CompareTo("AAAAAA") >= 0 &&
                d.MaxValue.CompareTo("CCCCCC") <= 0
 select d
```

Then it will give me all the rows in the database that corresponds to these min and max values, but if I try using a value that SHOULD fall within these two, nothing comes up.

Comment: You must swap the `<` and `>` signs.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do the trick either. If I get the generated SQL statement from LINQPad it becomes quite clear that is wants me to give the exact Min and Max value instead of finding a row where my value (x) is Between the MinValue column and MaxValue column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gert Arnold is correct, you're mixing up comparison operators.

For your original LINQ expression

```
from d in MyTable
          where d.MinValue.CompareTo("ABBBBC") >= 0 &&
                d.MaxValue.CompareTo("ABBBBC") <= 0
 select d
```

following SQL query is generated:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'ABBBBC'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'ABBBBC'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[MinValue], [t0].[MaxValue]
FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[MinValue] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[MaxValue] <= @p1)
```

whis is equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 'ABBBBC' BETWEEN MaxValue AND MinValue
```

that obviously is incorrect. Changing query to

```
from d in MyTable
          where d.MinValue.CompareTo("ABBBBC") <= 0 &&
                d.MaxValue.CompareTo("ABBBBC") >= 0
 select d
```

should produce required result. If you still consider it incorrect, please provide data row that you suppose should be returned by the query and your filtering value.

Comment: I have NO idea what I did yesterday, I must've been drunk or just way off, it worked like a charm. Thanks. :)